# clear all textboxes which all have id contains a particular string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have to clear all text box have  id contains f_evoucher. Is it possible to clear it in a single line using jquery or javascript?
i have already tried like below

```
document.getElementById("f_evoucher").value="";
document.getElementById("f_evoucher_2").value="";
document.getElementById("f_evoucher_3").value="";
document.getElementById("f_evoucher_4").value="";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [attribute starts](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with selector

```
$('[id^="f_evoucher"]').val('')
```

Note: It is very costly to use the attribute selector alone, so combine it with other selectors.

Ex: all the target elements are of type input then you can

```
$('input[id^="f_evoucher"]').val('')
```

Comment: there was no need for me to ans .u where fast then me

Answer (score 0):

Use [attribute start](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:It matches the starting string

```
$("[id^='f_evoucher']").val("");
```